# Check authentification for each request in Bottle

Tags: python, authorization, bottle

For every request in Bottle I would like to check if the request is eligible through HTTP authentication. My idea is to use a function, which is called at the start of every `@route` function.

```
def check_authentificaiton(requests):
    auth = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    credentials = parse_auth(auth)
    if credentials[0] is not 'user' or credentials[1] is not 'password':
        raise Exception('Request is not authorized')
```

This seems a bit redundant, since I want to protect every request, and it could fail if I forget to call it. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for a decorator which mandates a route to be accessed only if the user is loggedin. Like in the example below, `@require_uid` is a decorator which you can use around any function where you need user to be logged in. Flask has a [login_required decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/viewdecorators/).

[Using decorators to require sign in with bottle.py](http://tumblr.kurttheviking.com/post/13053496552/using-decorators-to-require-sign-in-with-bottle-py)

```
def require_uid(fn):
    def check_uid(**kwargs):   
        cookie_uid = request.get_cookie('cookieName', secret='cookieSignature')

        if cookie_uid:
            # do stuff with a user object
            return fn(**kwargs)
        else:
            redirect("/loginagain")

    return check_uid



@route('/userstuff', method='GET')
@require_uid
@view('app')
def app_userstuff():
    # doing things is what i like to do
    return dict(foo="bar")
```

Comment: I have also found the parameter `apply` for the `@route` decorator, shouldn't this be used over applying a decorator directly?

Comment: I am not a bottle.py pro, but the method I described is a pragamatic way of handling auth for functions. How are you using `apply`?

Comment: For instance this way: `@route('/userstuff', method='GET', apply=[require_uid])`. The documentation for apply says *A decorator or plugin or a list of plugins. These are applied to the route callback in addition to installed plugins.* No idea whether this makes any differences.

Comment: As per the documentation: `apply – A decorator or plugin or a list of plugins. These are applied to the route callback in addition to installed plugins.` So, `apply` is mainly used for calling decorators or plugins. I guess you can use it too.

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html